# Get Max value from Lookup

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a lookup like this:

```
ILookup<long ,float> vatPercentLookup = dataItems
  ?.GroupBy(x => x.VATRateId)
  ?.ToLookup(x => x.Key, z => z.Last().Percentage);
```

So i want to get max value from lookup like this :

```
var maxPercentage = vatPercentLookup[vatPercentLookup.Max().Key].First();
```

Please be careful i dont have access to dataItems any more.

I want to know it's the best way for get max value from lookup or not?

Comment: use `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

A lookup is the wrong type in your situation, it looks like you ought to be using a dictionary. Given that, you could just take the values of the dictionary and get the max of that. But you don't really need the intermediate representation when you could just do it all in a single query.

```
var maxPercentage = dataItems?
    .GroupBy(x => x.VATRateId, x => x.Percentage)
    .Select(g => g.Last())
    .Max();
```

Comment: I just want to get max value in lookup variable ,If i want to get max value from a linq query like your suggestion , i have to call another methods and fetch data from database again.